# Power Query - import .csv file from folder path and show the name of the file in the table

Tags: powerquery

I'm using power query to go to a folder look for csv files with a specific prefix and then return the one with the latest modified date.

As a check i want to add the filename into the returned table but i'm struggling. any ideas?

```
let 
    Source = Folder.Files("\\alignefsxprd.aws.edfenergy.net\share\ETRMHUB\Lookup\Config"),
    FilteredFiles = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.StartsWith([Name], "hedge_factors_config_")),
    MaxDateModified = List.Max(FilteredFiles[Date modified]),
    FilteredFilesMaxDate = Table.SelectRows(FilteredFiles, each [Date modified] = MaxDateModified),

    ImportData = Table.Combine(
        List.Transform(FilteredFilesMaxDate[Content], each Csv.Document(_, [Delimiter=",", Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]))
    ),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(ImportData, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    // Corrected column types specification
    ColumnTypes = {
        {"TEAM_FILE", type text}, 
        {"EFFECTIVE_FROM_DATETIME", type date}, 
        {"EFFECTIVE_TO_DATETIME", type date}, 
        {"BOOK_ATTRIBUTE_3", type text}, 
        {"BOOK_ATTRIBUTE_6", type text}, 
        {"BOOK_ATTRIBUTE_8", type text}, 
        {"FORECAST_BOOK", type text}, 
        {"HEDGE_BOOK", type text}, 
        {"TARGET_BOOK", type text}, 
        {"TRADE_GROUP_1", type text}, 
        {"FACTOR_START", type date}, 
        {"FACTOR_END", type date}, 
        {"STRATEGY_TYPE", type text}, 
        {"CARBON_TRADES", type text}, 
        {"AVERAGED", type text}, 
        {"MATRIX_FILE", type text}, 
        {"ALIGNE_DATE", type date}, 
        {"TARGET_DATE", type date}, 
        {"TARGET_FACTOR", type number}, 
        {"VOLUME_HEDGE", type text}

    },
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers", ColumnTypes)

in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let Source = Folder.Files("c:\temp\"),
FilteredFiles = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.StartsWith([Name], "hedge_factors_config_")),
MaxDateModified = List.Max(FilteredFiles[Date modified]),
FilteredFilesMaxDate = Table.SelectRows(FilteredFiles, each [Date modified] = MaxDateModified),
#"Added CSVdata" = Table.AddColumn(FilteredFilesMaxDate, "CSVdata", each Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document([Content])), type table),
#"Added Custom" =  Table.AddColumn(#"Added CSVdata", "Custom", each let name = [Name] in Table.AddColumn([CSVdata],"SourceFile", each name)),
#"Combined CSVdata" = Table.Combine(#"Added Custom"[Custom])
in #"Combined CSVdata"
```